# Conditional Code pipeline based on upstream action variable?

Tags: aws-codepipeline, aws-serverless

I know I can conditionally execute an aws codepipeline action based on a Condition, but I would like to base the actions execution instead on a dynamically set variable.

Is this possible?

Here's my use case:
I am using a monorepo with multiple workspaces. One for each microservice.  I have a lambda function that figures out which service source code was modified in every code push. It sets a variable with this info. Based on this variable I want to conditionally call microservice codebuild projects.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I know I can conditionally execute an aws codepipeline action based on
> a Condition

I would make the distinction here that you can modify the pipeline definition with a condition using cloudformation, and redploy the pipeline.

Code pipeline is biased towards trunk based development for a single repo so you are making your life difficult by trying to work against that.

If you must do this as far as I can see:

1. Move the conditional logic into each code build project, they would run but do something or not based on the conditional logic.
2. A pipeline can update itself.

Note **RestartExecutionOnUpdate** set with a condition.

```
  Pipeline:
    Type: AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
    Properties:
      RestartExecutionOnUpdate: !If [ RestartPipelineOnUpdate, true, false ]
      RoleArn: !ImportValue CodePipelineRoleArn
      Name: !Ref CodePipelineName
```

Then the pipeline can have an action that deploys the stack with it's own definition - very meta.

```
        - !If
          - ShouldUpatePipelineStackOnChange
          - Name: UpdatePipeline
            Actions:
              - Name: CreateChangeSet
                ActionTypeId:
                  Category: Deploy
                  Owner: AWS
                  Provider: CloudFormation
                  Version: "1"
                Configuration:
                  ActionMode: CREATE_UPDATE 
                  StackName: !Ref AWS::StackName
                  TemplatePath: !Sub ${PipelineCodeArtifactName}::${ThisTemplateName}
                  Capabilities: CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM
                  RoleArn: !GetAtt PipelineStackCloudFormationExecutionRole.Arn
                InputArtifacts:
                  - Name: !Sub ${PipelineCodeArtifactName}
                RunOrder: 1
          - !Ref AWS::NoValue
```

If you had something like:

- Cloudformation Parameters set to Dynamic values in the
  parameter store that govern if codebuild projects run.
- The pipeline calls a Lambda that sets those parameter values.
- The Lambda runs before the 'UpdatePipeline' action.

The 'UpdatePipeline' would redeploy the stack. If a change was detected, the pipeline definition would get updated and the pipeline would start again.

Theoretically the above could work.

Comment: Thanks @onan-cunningham. I tried doing something similar to what you suggested. was painful to implement but got it working.  and it was cool to see the pipeline transform itself automatically after each commit.  I used a lambda to trigger a cloudformation deploy (of the same template) with updated parameters.   Unfortunately, this solution seems to be buggy.  If a secondary commit enters the pipeline and transforms it while a previous one is still executing, then the previous commit gets removed -- very thanos like.  it leaves the various environments in an inconsistent state. :-( oh well

Comment: I'm swimming upstream with CodePipeline.  CircleCi makes it incredibly easy to do what i need, so I'm making the switch https://github.com/CircleCI-Public/api-preview-docs/blob/path-filtering/docs/path-filtering.md#using-the-path-filtering-orb.   Plus, i like the idea of not having cloudformation stacks and s3 buckets cluttered with both ci/cd and application stuff.